# Creating CON.shp in ArcPy gives ERROR 000732

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, clip, error-000732, arcgis-10.6

I am creating  bunch of point shapefiles by using watershed boundaries in a loop

```
import arcpy
from collections import defaultdict

geo_db = 'C:\\CHIA_Routine\\CHIA_Watersheds.gdb'
smis_wq_resultsXY = geo_db + 'smis_wq_resultsXY'
huc12_370 = geo_db + '\\HUC12_370'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(huc12_370, ['WatershedD', 'CIAMaster', 'Code3', 'HUC_12']) as cursor:
    n = 1
    for row in cursor:
        watershed_report_dic[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2], row[3], n]
        watershed_shp_dic[row[1]] = [row[0], row[2], row[3], n]
        n = n+1


    for watershed in watershed_shp_dic.keys(): 
        code3 = watershed_shp_dic[watershed][1]
        code3_prefix = main_folder + '\\' + 'Watershed_DataSets' + '\\' + watershed_shp_dic[watershed][0] + '\\' + code3
        code3_path = main_folder + '\\' + 'Watershed_DataSets' + '\\' + watershed_shp_dic[watershed][0]
        arcpy.Clip_analysis(smis_wq_resultsXY, geo_db + '\\' + code3, code3_prefix + '.shp')
```

code3 is three letter unique code for each watershed. When code3 is 'CON' it gives me error:

```
ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset C:\CHIA_Routine\Watershed_DataSets\Contrary_Creek_Kentucky_River\CON does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (Clip)
```

If I changed both output shapefilename and watershed code then it works. I thought maybe 'CON' is a reserved word.

Is it possible to select a polygon from a polygon shapefile and export it as CON.shp without getting ERROR 000732?

.

Comment: Best practice is to use the `os.path.join` function to assemble names instead of doing string math. The error indicates the second parameter has neither a valid geodatabase table name nor a suffix, so it's not surprising that it fails. Your code doesn't report the contents of the variables used, so it's nearly impossible to reproduce your error. File geodatabase has a number of [documented reserved words](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010906), but `CON` is not among them.

Comment: @Vince I can not even generate a shapefile named CON.shp by doing it manually.

Comment: "*Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file: CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension*" - [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#naming-conventions)

Comment: @user2856 I think thats the problem. It is not related to ArcGIS but Microsoft was preventing to create the shapefile. I already adjusted my code with different name but it is good to know what was going on. Thank you! if you post it as answer I will accept it.

Comment: I did create a file geodatabase feature class named "con", but couldn't create "con.shp". No idea why this is the case.

Comment: @Vince that was the case for me as well. user2856 's comment addressing the issue I believe. Thanks for your help and comment!

Comment: @user2856 This question is now open ready for you to answer if you get a  chance.

Comment: Yowza!  **Don't** try to create `prn.shp` -- It hung my ArcMap application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that CON is a Windows reserved word.

From [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#naming-conventions):

> Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file: CON,
>   PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9,
>   LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9.
>
> Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension.

If you *must* use shapefiles rather than a geodatabase featureclass for whatever reason, I would name them with the 3 letter code and some other known characters that can easily be parsed later.  Something like "code_con.shp", or whatever you like.

Comment: it would be nice if ESRI can document this.

Comment: It's not an Esri issue.  But a better error message would help.